# User and picture models

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have the following models:

1. User
2. Picture
3. Variant

User `has_many` pictures, picture `has_many` variants.

Variant has value price and I am trying to find the price of all pictures of selected (e.g. for user id 15) current user.

First I tried like this:

```
def value(user)

  total = 0

  user.pictures.each do |picture|

    picture.variants.each do |variant|
      total += variant.price
    end

  end

  total.to_f

end
```

How could I improve this code so that I can avoid the N+1 problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with just one query. There are variations how to construct the query but I would probably do something like this:

```
picture_ids = user.pictures.select(:id) # Will be used as a subquery if you use select
Variant.where(picture_id: picture_ids).sum(:price)
```

This will only generate one query, and sum all the prices using sql, so you don't lose performance.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comment below, if you are using MySQL (or have a SQL server which does not handle subqueries that good) you can use `pluck` instead of `select`. That will make as separate query to fetch all the `picture_ids` and everything else will still work the same way.

Comment: With MySQL you need to be careful about using sub-selects as their performance is not very good (see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14565/mysql-subquery-slows-down-drastically-but-they-work-fine-independently) iirc, Oracle and PostgreSQL optimize the query better.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1) Add a has_many though clause to your user object:

```
class User
  has_many :pictures
  has_many :variant,  through: :pictures
  ...
```

You could also explicitly join tables into a single query:

```
Variants.joins(:pictures).where(pictures: {user: user} )
```

I would also use the `sum` method to do the query on the database server:

```
user.variant.sum(:price)
```